# NULL Value from SQL Server DB becomes "&nbsp;" when evaluating its cell in RadGrid

Tags: sql-server, string, vb.net, radgrid, dataitem

I have a grid being populated by SQL data. In my dataBound method I have a numerical condition that evaluates the text of particular cells, for example: if myCell.Text <90

It is possible for the cell to have NULL values, so I want to check before running these conditions to ensure that the cell is not null. However, the actual text in the cell is evaluated as "nbsp;" (removed the & so it will appear in this post). I don't want to hardcode something like NOT myCell.Text.Contains("nbsp") because that just feels sloppy and problematic.

```
If TypeOf e.Item Is GridDataItem Then
    Dim dataItem As GridDataItem = e.Item
    Dim myCell As TableCell = dataItem("Status")
    If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(myCell.Text) Then
```

This is my current code and obviously the string " " passes this condition.

How do I properly check this value? Is there a different property I can evaluate?

Comment: I'm confused: is the value `null` or `"&nbsp;"` or the single NBSP character `" "`? Or is it actually `DBNull.Value` which is what you would get if using a `DataTable` or `DataReader`?

Comment: @Charlieface the value of myCell.Text is literally "&nbsp;"

Comment: Well how did that value get there? Maybe you should be correcting your data at source, in your database? Or in the `SELECT` statement that pulls out the data? Otherwise what's wrong with just checking for that string? How is "obviously the string " " passes this condition" relevant to the question?

Comment: @Charlieface Sorry I guess I'm just looking to understand this issue so I can implement this in a better way? The source data is correct and shows NULL in sql. Sorry if this is a waste of time I was hoping to gain some insight into why this would happen or if it's a known problem that can be worked around without "cheating"

Comment: Take a look at the couple of answers to this question, that talk about either setting the "Null value" text, or regarding HTML encoding/decoding.  If you're not aware, &nbsp; is a standard HTML output for rendering a "space" character in the browser.  It seems your RadGrid is expecting that it should be outputting empty values (be that actually Null, or just an empty string/space character) - but, obviously you're not specifically wanting that.  There should be some property (or properties) that you can set on the RadGrid to change this behaviour (sorry that I don't know specifically)

Comment: Why not put a breakpoint in that code and inspect the value of these "nulls".  Although coming from a Sql DB would guess it's DBNull.Value you're looking for

Comment: I don't use that control but my guess would be that you're using the `Text` property. The actual text displayed in a control and the value that that text represents are often not the same thing. If the display is HTML then the non-breaking space is probably required to make it look right. Is there another property, e.g. `Value`, that contains the actual data in that cell, rather than the text representing that data? Consider the fact that `Text` is always going to be a `String` but non-null data could be `Integer` or `Date` or any other type.

Comment: `if myCell.Text <90` is comparing a `String` to an `Integer` so that obviously makes no sense from the outset. You should turn `Option Strict On` in your project and start respecting data types. You'll write better code as a result.

Comment: The `Text` values have already been formatted by the grid for presentation purposes. If you need access to the raw values have you read through [Accessing Raw Field Data and Key Values](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/accessing-values-and-controls/server-side/accessing-cells#accessing-raw-field-data-and-key-values) yet?

Answer (score 0):

This is a behavior of telerik's radgrid. To change the behavior, set the EmptyDataText field belonging to GridBoundColumn. You can see from the second link below that the default value of a gridBoundColumn is `" "` which is then converted to `&nbsp;` by the html encoder.

A like to the documentation for GridBoundColumn is here: [Telerik GridBoundColumn](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/columns/column-types#gridboundcolumn)

and [Telerik GridboundColumn Server Side API Reference](https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/api/server/telerik.web.ui/gridboundcolumn#emptydatatext)